# "As far as I can remember." Does it need comma if put at the end of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, clauses, punctuation, commas

> I've always been interested in music, as far as I can remember.
>
> I've always been interested in music as far as I can remember.

What's the correct option? Or at least the most common one?

Comment: I think it depends on the meaning you're after.  With the comma I'd interpret it as putting a caveat on the previous statement:  *I've always been interested in music, [at least] as far as I can remember, that is.*  Without the comma it is expressing the great length of time over which your interest has spanned: *As far back as I can remember, I've **always** been interested in music.*

Comment: @Jim hey, you're right. Why don't you post this as an answer? It's pretty good.

Comment: Actually, @Jim is just partly right here. With the comma, the sentence means as he suggests *(at least as far . . . ). But the statement without the comma does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence does need a comma there because the dependent clause *as far as I can remember* adds *nonessential* information following an independent clause.

Note the main rule about a dependent clause following an independent clause in a complex sentence, and (pertinant here), the exception to the rule that follows.

> Rule: If the independent clause comes before the dependent clause, omit the comma.
>
> You shouldn’t be driving if you can’t see without your glasses.
>
> Our flight has been delayed because of the thunderstorm.
>
> Exception to the rule: If the dependent clause is not essential to the meaning of the sentence, it should be set off with a comma.
>
> I cannot agree with his position on that issue, though I don’t doubt 
>    his sincerity. (Not doubting his sincerity is not the reason I cannot agree with his position; it is 
>    merely an additional piece of information.)

From [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html#complexsentences)

Comment: -1 because the dependent clause of the second sentence does not have to be read as adding 'extra information'